# Json.Net: JsonSerializer-Attribute for custom naming

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I use the `JsonSerializer` from Newtonsoft.

But i want to name the json-objects by myself.

I tried the `JsonObject` attribute

```
[JsonObject(Description = "MyName", Title = "orThisname")]
```

`JsonArray` also didnt work...
Is it possible to name the json-objetcs/arrays by myself?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Myname")]
```

will rename it.

Comment: Why did this get accepted? This does not give the object itself a name, that is what is being asked. This renames a property marked for serialization.