# Create JSON with C# Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to create the following JSON data:

```
{
'chart.labels': ['Bob','Lucy','Gary','Hoolio'],
'chart.tooltips': ['Bob did well',
               'Lucy had her best result',
               'Gary - not so good',
               'Hoolio had a good start'
              ]
}
```

I am using C# and trying to create an object in order to do this.....something like:

```
public class chart{
 public string[] chart.labels {get;set;}
 public string[] chart.tooltips {get;set;}
}
```

but obviously I cannot have properties containing spaces.

How would I go about doing this ?

**UPDATE:**

Using JamieC's answer the following works perfecly

```
public virtual ActionResult CompanyStatus()
    {
        var labelList = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Lucy", "Gary", "Hoolio" };
        var tooltipsList = new List<string>() { "Bob did well", "Lucy had her best result", "Gary - not so good", "Hoolio had a good start" };

        var cData = new chartData()
        {
            Labels = labelList.ToArray(),
            Tooltips = tooltipsList.ToArray()
        };

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(cData.GetType());
        String output;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, cData);
            output = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        } 

        return this.Content(output);
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class chartData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "chart.labels")]
        public string[] Labels { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "chart.tooltips")]
        public string[] Tooltips { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
{"chart.labels":["Bob","Lucy","Gary","Hoolio"],"chart.tooltips":["Bob did well","Lucy had her best result","Gary - not so good","Hoolio had a good start"]}
```

Comment: Do you mean "properties that contain periods (dots)" instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use a `DataContractJsonSerializer` to turn your object into Json, and use `DataMember` attributes to annotate what names to use for properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class ChartModel{
 [DataMember(Name = "chart.labels")]
 public string[] Labels {get;set;}
 [DataMember(Name = "chart.tooltips")]
 public string[] Tooltips {get;set;}
}
```

I personally use my own `ActionResult` to wrap up the serialization in MVC:

```
public class JsonDataContractResult : ActionResult
{
    public JsonDataContractResult(Object data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    protected JsonDataContractResult()
    {

    }

    public Object Data { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(this.Data.GetType());
        String output; 
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, this.Data);
            output = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        } 
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(output);
    }        
}
```

And return that from a helper method in a base controller:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController: Controller
{

    protected JsonDataContractResult JsonContract(Object data)
    {
        return new JsonDataContractResult(data);
    }

}
```

Then my controller becomes really simple:

```
public class SomeController: MyBaseController
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    { 
        var model = new ChartModel()
                   { 
                       Labels = ..., 
                       Tooltips = ... 
                   };
        return JsonContract(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JamieC - Got the simple part working now. Will add your methods next :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.NET library, you can download it from [here](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

It has this feature:

> Attribute property name customization

This question will help you:

[Json.Net: JsonSerializer-Attribute for custom naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860602/json-net-jsonserializer-attribute-for-custom-naming)

And you can use **DataContractJsonSerializer** it provides this feature, but **JavaScriptSerializer** is not.

Comment: Absolutely. Awesome library.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC project `Newtonsoft.Json` library is available.(You have to manually include this for other projects)

So give `JsonProperty` in the model, like this...

```
public class ChartModel{
    [JsonProperty("chart.labels")]
    public string[] Labels {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("chart.tooltips")]
    public string[] Tooltips {get;set;}
}
```

and use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);` or `Json.Encode(object)` to convert to JSON.