# How to serialize JSON that uses keywords for names?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to make a JSON string like this using JSON.NET:

```
{
  "description": "the description",
  "public": true,
  "files": {
    "index.html": {
      "content": "some value"
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I do that?

I tried creating a class for it, but I don't know how to create a field with name `"public"` because `public` is C# keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860602/json-net-jsonserializer-attribute-for-custom-naming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property name could be anything you want, but if you want the value to map to it, you need to add the `JsonProperty` attribute indicating the name of the property.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("public")]
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, JObject> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your really helped me!